# HTML call a JS function to disable radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, radio-button

On my webpage I want to disable certain radio buttons if a certain selection is made from a dropdown list.

Below is my head section:

```
<head>
<script> 
    function myRadio() {
        if {
        document.getElementById("time").value = "19.30";
        return document.getElementById("duration_120").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

This is my body section:

```
<select name="time" form="bookingForm" id="time" onchange="return myRadio()">
  <option value="19.00">19.00</option>
  <option value="19.30">19.30</option>
  <option value="20.00">20.00</option>
  <option value="20.30">20.30</option>
</select>
<label>Duration: </label><br>
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_30" value="30">30 mins
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_60" value="60">60 mins
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_90" value="90">90 mins
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_120" value="120">120 mins
```

So what i want to do is if a time of 19.30 is selected then i want to disable (grey out) the 120 mins radio button. And if 20.30 is selceted then i want to disable the 60, 90 & 120 mins radio buttons.
There is also more selection options before 19.00 that I wish all the radio buttons to be enabled for.

The function that I am currently trying is not working so any help on how to do this is appreciated.
Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```js
disableDurationTimeMap = {
  '19.30': [120],
  '20.30': [60, 90, 120]
};

function disableDurationsForTime(timeValue) {
  var disableDurations = disableDurationTimeMap[timeValue];
  if (disableDurations === undefined) { return; }
  disableDurations.forEach(function(duration) {
    document.querySelector('input[name="duration"][value="' + duration.toString() + '"]').disabled = true;
  });
}

function enableAllDurations() {
  var durations = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="duration"]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(durations, function(input) {
    input.disabled = false;
  });
}
var timeSelect = document.getElementById('time');
timeSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  enableAllDurations();
  var selectedTime = timeSelect.options[timeSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  disableDurationsForTime(selectedTime);
});
```

```html
<select name="time" form="bookingForm" id="time">
  <option value="19.00">19.00</option>
  <option value="19.30">19.30</option>
  <option value="20.00">20.00</option>
  <option value="20.30">20.30</option>
</select>
<label>Duration:</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_30" value="30">30 mins
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_60" value="60">60 mins
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_90" value="90">90 mins
<input type="radio" name="duration" id="duration_120" value="120">120 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript, i think this is what you want...

```
function myRadio() {

//Enable all (the 'each' way, with no jquery)
document.getElementById('duration_120').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('duration_90').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('duration_60').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('duration_30').disabled = false;

//switch for undefined options and durations
switch(document.getElementById('time').value) {

  // 1 case for each option
  case '19.30':
  document.getElementById('duration_120').disabled = true;
  break;

  case '20.30':
  document.getElementById('duration_120').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('duration_90').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('duration_60').disabled = true;
  break;

 }

}
```